# Can not type \, | and ~ on Ubuntu inside Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, sudo, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

I have installed a Virtual Box Ubuntu 14.04.

I run into two very basic problems:

1. Somehow I cannot type `\ |  ~`  characters in terminal or textfile. It is a clean and fresh install under Virtual Box.
2. In attempt to solve problem 1, I try to rename or remove `/etc/inputrc`. (`~/.inputrc` seems not to exist in my user folder). But how do I use graphical `sudo` to obtain the rights to rename or remove the file? 
   Or how do I get about problem 1 otherwise?

Comment: I do not think inputrc is related. It's either the keyboard setting inside the virtual box, or outside (or both).

Comment: How do you know you can not type \ , `|` and `~`? Did you try combinations with AltGr?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have now discovered that it is the Alt- Gr button that is not working. Not in terminal, Writer, Gedit... You think that concerns Virtual Box settings?

Comment: I do not use virtualbox, but check whether one keyboard is set to `us`, and one is not, or so.

Comment: I have changed Virtual Box input settings to make Hostkey something else than Right-Ctrl, as suggested somewhere. Still no result. Keyboard setting is Belgian both in host and in virtual machine, not US. Somewhere they speak about changing a file .Xmodmap but I understand nihil of it.

Comment: I do not know the Belgian keymap, but can you link to the .Xmodmap thing?

Comment: http://blacketernal.wordpress.com/set-up-key-mappings-with-xmodmap/     and    https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkeyboard-config/+bug/349487/comments/1

Comment: That should be only a problem if you have that file, if I read correctly. Can you check? `ls -l $HOME/.Xmodmap`

Comment: "No such file or directory"   So this again is not the route to take. I would have switched to VMWare, were it not that VMWare was my first choice but there I could not even login to Ubuntu at first logon. So I tried Virtual Box and it got me a lot farther, but I'm lost on this one.

Comment: That's good - then, the issue with .Xmodmap does not apply, if I read it right.

Comment: Thats good? :) Ok I believe you

Comment: I am thinking (having continued scouting the net) that the issue is with the Virtual Box Guest additions software piece. I read in posts from years back that it is a returning issue with Guest additions. However I fond no solutions posted...

Comment: Just found this post confirming that it is a bug in Virtual Box 4.3.14 (what I am using): https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62687.  Conclusion, I will have to downgrade to previous version, and accept that I'll lose everything I had accomplished today. Fieww

Comment: Ohh... not the solution one would hope for :) You can answer your question yourself with that result. Just post the last comment about the bug as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The OP found that the the problem is caused by a bug in Virtualbox:*

The issue is related to the VirtualBox "Guest additions" software.

This post confirms there is a bug in version 4.3.14:
http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62687

VirtualBox 4.3.14 is the latest version, which I am using.
As a work around I will downgrade to an earlier version.

The page also provides a test build of VirtualBox 4.3.15.

---

<sub>@user3817704 This answer is derived from the comments you made on the question. The comments can get lost, so I make it an answer. Feel free to answer yoursef or build your answer on this, I will remove my answer then.</sub>

Comment: I completely agree with your answer, thanks and regards.